# How to use cached file in Google Speech-to-Text?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, caching, yii2, speech-to-text

There is a similar code example on the official Google page:

```php
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\SpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionAudio;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig\AudioEncoding;

/**
 * @param string $audioFile path to an audio file
 */
function transcribe_async(string $audioFile)
{
    // change these variables if necessary
    $encoding = AudioEncoding::LINEAR16;
    $sampleRateHertz = 32000;
    $languageCode = 'en-US';

    // get contents of a file into a string
    $content = file_get_contents($audioFile);

    // set string as audio content
    $audio = (new RecognitionAudio())
        ->setContent($content);

    // set config
    $config = (new RecognitionConfig())
        ->setEncoding($encoding)
        ->setSampleRateHertz($sampleRateHertz)
        ->setLanguageCode($languageCode);

    // create the speech client
    $client = new SpeechClient();

    // create the asyncronous recognize operation
    $operation = $client->longRunningRecognize($config, $audio);
    $operation->pollUntilComplete();

    if ($operation->operationSucceeded()) {
        $response = $operation->getResult();

        // each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. iterate
        // through them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
        foreach ($response->getResults() as $result) {
            $alternatives = $result->getAlternatives();
            $mostLikely = $alternatives[0];
            $transcript = $mostLikely->getTranscript();
            $confidence = $mostLikely->getConfidence();
            printf('Transcript: %s' . PHP_EOL, $transcript);
            printf('Confidence: %s' . PHP_EOL, $confidence);
        }
    } else {
        print_r($operation->getError());
    }

    $client->close();
}
```

I need to make it so that I can get the data from the **Yii2** cache and use it in this code. How can I achieve this?

I tried to create a temporary file, it did not work. But maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: In the example this `$content = file_get_contents($audioFile);` loads the content of audio file into variable. Then this `$audio = (new RecognitionAudio())
        ->setContent($content);` wraps the content in some google's wrapper. If you get the content of audio file from cache you shouldn't need to create temp file. Just skip the `file_get_contents` step and put the content directly to `RecognitionAudio` wrapper. Btw. If you want us to find why your code is not working you will have to give us your code instead of google's example code.